# How can I use a timestamp to name a gnuplot file?

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to name my gnuplot out file with the date and time it was created?
I currently create files with set names as follows:

```
     set term post eps color
     set output '/path/dateandtime.eps'
     plot
     set term x11
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the builtin function `time` to get the current timestamp and `strftime`to format it:

```
set output strftime('/path/%F_%H-%M-%S.eps', time(0))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the output from an external command as a string with the `system` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

date = system("date +%F.%H.%M.%S")
set term ...
set output '/path/'.date.'.eps'
plot
```

The `.` operator concatenates strings.